# Python + Selenium: send_keys sending spaces, instead of numbers, to text box

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python and I'm trying to fill this text box with my birthday using send_keys (Firefox). However, send_keys doesn't work properly; instead of sending the keys "01012012", it sends spaces only.

I've noticed using Safari's WebDriver works, but it doesn't with Firefox's or Chrome's.

This is the element:

```
<label class="cont\_input filledDob filled invalid" style="width:100%; margin:18px 0 0 0; float:left; position:relative; padding:10px 0 0 0;">

<input type="text" name="dob" value="" maxlength="10" class="input\_login input\_date" placeholder="Dia / Mês / Ano" tabindex="3" id="dob" required="" aria-required="true" title="Por favor, forneça uma data válida. Ex: 01/01/2012">

<span class="txt\_form" style="width:250px;">Data de Nascimento</span>
<span class="txt\_form">DD/MM/AAAA</span>
</label>
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("dob").send_keys("01012012")
```

I have also tried clicking the element, then sending HOME key and then sending the date, but it also doesn't work.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. Is it possible to know the website so we can try it out?

Comment: This is the website I'm testing: https://www.clear.com.br/pit/signin?controller=SignIn

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely an interesting one. For some reason, almost half of the time the input just doesn't get correctly entered. I have written a little workaround that you may use that seems to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver

inputDOB = "01012012"
enteredDOB = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(inputDOB[:2], inputDOB[2:4], inputDOB[4:])

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.clear.com.br/pit/signin?controller=SignIn")
dob = browser.find_element_by_name("dob")
while (dob.get_attribute('value') != enteredDOB):
    dob.clear()
    dob.send_keys(inputDOB)
```

Edit: Explanation

inputDOB is your normal input that you will be giving in.

When you compare the value of the dob field, it will return a value like MM/DD/YYYY, including the slashes. So I created an enteredDOB variable which is really the same as inputDOB but with the slashes.

So for an inputDOB = "01012012", enteredDOB = "01/01/2012"

Comment: Awesome! I'll try as soon as I get home. Would you mind explaining the enteredDOB variable, please, as I'll need to input a different date?

Comment: Sure, added a simple explanation

Comment: This is the result I got: https://gph.is/g/aeAnR0A. It keeps trying to add the value.

Comment: What webdriver are you using?

Comment: Latest geckodriver

Comment: I've edited the loop to only dob.send_keys(inputDOB). The box seems to be empty, but if you select the text box swipping to the left, you will see the dob there. However, it's still not typing correctly, as it is not accepting the value to login.

Comment: Hmm, I run into the same issue with geckodriver. Works on chromedriver though. Can you clarify what you mean by swiping to the left?

Comment: Something very funky is going on. If I open up developer console in firefox, then it seems to type the text.

Comment: https://gph.is/g/aN86DbP > Here. If I manually do that (select by dragging the mouse to the left after it runs the loop, it will show the dob and the login will work. However, If let it click the login button without manually doing that, it won't accept the credentials. The loop is the same as you wrote, but without the clear() function.
Edit: You're right! if the dev console is open, it will work correctly. lol

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry but im completely stumped with this one. If you're able to switch to chromedriver I would suggest that. Something funky is going on with firefox. And this webpage is not handling the input normally. Even if I try to set the value attribute directly, it does not reflect. My guess is there is some javascript behind the scenes taking the input because even with an invalid value attribute set, I can enter some valid numbers and submit.

Comment: That's alright! Thank you for helping! I'll stick to Safari, then.